# Issue with a Core Data Model in a svn repository

Tags: svn, ios, core-data

I am working on an iOS app in XCode 4.  I am unable to commit the Data Model (.xcdatamodeld) to my subversion repository.  The svn tool in xcode is a bit lacking so I went to the command line.

When I type "svn status", it shows a '?' beside my .xcdatamodeld file, which means it is not under version control.

When I do an "svn add" for the .xcdatamodeld, it tells me that it is already under version control.

I think this is more of an SVN issue.  Any idea what could cause this contradiction?

jorj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you move any directories or folders around?

I've found odd behaviour when one local repository gets another's metadata because the embedded `.svn' directories moved into the other local repository along with the folder.

Comment: Thank you much!  I had done some moving and since a data model is a directory (with another directory in it), some lingering .svn dirs were screwing it up.  It's all working now.

Answer (score 4):

When you create a new version xcode copies the .svn directory.

Solution: remove the .svn directory in the new version directory:

```
rm -rf DataModel.xcdatamodeld/DataModel\ 2.xcdatamodel/.svn
```